# Basic subsequence of weak* convergent sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence, schauder-basis

I have given the following theorem :
Let $(\phi_n)$ is a sequence on $S_{X^*}$ (unit sphere of topological dual of the Banach space $X$). If $(f_n)$ is weak* convergent to zero then $f_n$ has a basic subsequence i.e. $\exists (f_{n_k})\subset(f_n)$ such that $\{f_{n_k}:k\in\mathbb N\}$ is a Schauder basis of $\overline{span\{f_{n_k}:k\in\mathbb N\}}$.

I am trying to prove that the theorem below is a direct consequence of the given theorem.

Theorem : Let $(x_n)$ is a sequence on $S_{X}$. If $(x_n)$ is weak convergent to zero then $x_n$ has a basic subsequence.

I thought using canonical mapping that is $J:X\to(X^*)^*$ where $(J_x)(f)=f(x), \quad \forall f\in X^*, \forall x\in X$. By using this we have $X$ is homeomorphic to $J(X)\subseteq(X^*)^*$.

I am not sure this way is proper or not. If it is true how can I proceed from there?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Do you mean $x_n$ being weakly convergent? Then your theorem tells you that $x_n$ admits a basic sub-sequence (as a sub-sequence of $X^{**}$). Use that  the span of $x_{n_k}$ is in $X\subseteq X^{**}$ so its closure is also in $X$. Then its a schauder basis of a subspace of $X$ and you are done.